# How to get the uploaded image name from the store method

Tags: laravel, image, upload

When I store an image in Laravel by doing:

```
$path = $request->file('myImage')->store('public/src/');
```

It returns the full path, but how do I get only the filename it was given?

This is an example of the returned path:

`public/src/ltX4COwEmvxVqX4Lol81qfJZuPTrQO6S2jsicuyp.png`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Laravel, the `store()` method generates the name dynamically .. so you can't get it from the `store()` method.

But you can use `storeAs()` method. Basically the `store()` method is calling the `storeAs()` method. So:

```
$path = $request->file('myImage')->store('public/src');
```

What Laravel is doing is calling `->storeAs('public/src', $request->file('myImage')->hashName());` .. you see the `hashName()` method? that is what generates the name.

So you can call `hashName()` first and know your name before the storing happens .. here is an example:

```
$uploadFile = $request->file('myImage');
$file_name = $uploadFile->hashName();
$path = $uploadFile->storeAs('public/src', $file_name);
```

Now you have `$file_name` and `$path`.

See:

- https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/filesystem#file-uploads .. Specifying A File Name
- https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/6.x/src/Illuminate/Http/UploadedFile.php#L33
- https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/6.x/src/Illuminate/Http/FileHelpers.php#L42

Answer (score 2):

Here, you can try this one.

```
    $fileNameWithExt = $request->file('myImage')->getClientOriginalName();
    $fileNameWithExt = str_replace(" ", "_", $fileNameWithExt);

    $filename = pathinfo($fileNameWithExt, PATHINFO_FILENAME);
    $filename = preg_replace("/[^a-zA-Z0-9\s]/", "", $filename);
    $filename = urlencode($filename);

    $extension = $request->file('myImage')->getClientOriginalExtension();

    $fileNameToStore = $filename.'_'.time().'.'.$extension;

    $path = $request->file('myImage')->storeAs('public/src/',$fileNameToStore);
    return $fileNameToStore;
```

You will get your stored filename in **$fileNameToStore**.
Also, all the spaces will be replaced with "_" and you will get your stored filename with current time attached with it, which will help you differentiate between two files with the same name.

Comment: What does this `"/[^a-zA-Z0-9\s]/"` means?

Comment: @IbrahimShendy These are the regular expressions that define different types of characters and set of characters. For a detailed explanation of regular expression, you can refer [here](https://www.cs.wcupa.edu/rkline/index/regular-expressions.html)

Answer (score 2):

Since `$path` returns the full path to the saved file, it contains its generated name.
You have just to parse this string :

```
$extension = explode('/', $path);
$filename = end($extension)
```

which will give you `ltX4COwEmvxVqX4Lol81qfJZuPTrQO6S2jsicuyp.png`