# Image store but not show proper path in laravel API

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-4, postman, laravel-api

How can i store actually path in database and how can i fetch image in API?
This is output of API in postman [image]

This is database which show store path of image but its wrong..

[image]

```html
 public function store(Request $request)
    {
        
        $event = $request->all(); 
           if ($request->hasFile('file')) {
$destinationPath = public_path().'/public/img/';
$file = $request->file;
$fileName = time() . '.'.$file->clientExtension();
$file->move($destinationPath, $fileName);
$input['e_image'] = $fileName;
}

            // $return['success'] = true,
            // $return['data'] = $event,
            // $return['msg'] = "this is message ";
             $success['status'] = true;
             $success['data'] = [$event];
             $success['message'] ="Event created successfully!";
             // $success['event'] = $event;
             return response()->json($success); 
    }
```

Comment: where is code store data in DB?

Comment: In store function..you can check in question -@ShaileshLadumor

Comment: You must upload your image in your storage folder and then store the filename in your database which you retrieved after uploading the image. While passing the data in your API, append the URL link to your storage with the image name. You can find a better image uploading block of code here. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58856971/how-to-get-the-uploaded-image-name-from-the-store-method/58857156#58857156

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**$file = new YOURMODELNAME(); please enter your model name in this line of code**

```
public function store(Request $request)
     {
        $input = $request->all();
        $rules = array(
            'e_image' => 'required|mimes:jpeg,png,jpg,doc,docx,pdf,mp4,mov,ogg,qt',
       'e_group' => required,
       'e_invite'=>required,
        );
        $validator = Validator::make($input, $rules);
        if ($validator->fails()) {
            $arr = array("status" => 400, "message" => $validator->errors()->first(), "data" => array());
        } else {
            try {
                $file = $request->file('e_image');
                $input['e_image'] = time() . '.' . $file->getClientOriginalExtension();
                $destinationPath = public_path('/img/');
                $file->move($destinationPath, $input['e_image']);




                $file = new YOURMODELNAME();





                $file->e_image = $input['e_image'];
                $file->e_group = $input['e_group'];
                $file->e_invite = $input['e_invite'];
                $file->save();
                $file->e_image = url('public/img/' . $file->e_image);


                $arr = array("status" => 200, "message" => "file upload Successfully", "data" => $file);
            } catch (\Exception $ex) {
                if (isset($ex->errorInfo[2])) {
                    $msg = $ex->errorInfo[2];
                } else {
                    $msg = $ex->getMessage();
                }
                $arr = array("status" => 400, "message" => $msg, "data" => array());
            }
        }
        return \Response::json($arr);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

please try this one and store image in proper project directory with unique image name .

```html
                $img = $request->profile_image;
                $old_path = public_path() . "/public/img/";
                $image_parts = explode(";base64,", $img);
                $image_type_aux = explode("image/", $image_parts[0]);
                $image_type = $image_type_aux[1];
                $image_base64 = base64_decode($image_parts[1]);
                $filename = uniqid() . '.png';
                $file = $old_path . $filename;
                file_put_contents($file, $image_base64);
                
                if (file_exists(public_path('/public/img/' . $filename))) {
                   //move image
                   $new_path = public_path() . "/public/img/newimages/";
                   if (!is_dir($new_path)) {
                       mkdir($new_path, 0777, TRUE);
                   }
                   $move = File::move($old_path . $filename, $new_path . $filename);
               }
               
               //upload image at database
               $modalObj = new table();
               $modalObj->updateById(\Session::get('table')->id, [
                   'profile_photo' => $filename,
               ]);
               return response()->json(['code' => '1', 'message' => 'Image Uploaded successfully!!!', 'data' => ['imageName' => url('/public/img/newimages/' . $filename)]]);
```

Comment: sorry Actually i didn't understand your code. -@PHP Geek

Comment: He already stores a unique image name. `$fileName = time() . '.'.$file->clientExtension();` this line create unique time with extension isn't it?

Comment: Yes it is -@DilipHirapara

Comment: I understand only my code, could you examine the error in my code?-@PHP Geek